# How do I send 2 custom conditional responses with Twilio in Python and Flask?

Tags: python, flask, sms, twilio, twilio-twiml

I am trying to essentially loop through the Flask app with Twilio so that when a user texts a Twilio number, Twilio will greet the user but will be awaiting a second response from the user. Basically:

user texts twilio number -> twilio app greets and prompts user for another response -> user enters 2nd response by texting twilio number again -> twilio acknowledges and transaction is marked done

I get the first half of the functionality I want with:

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/sms", methods=['GET','POST'])
def sms_logic():

    # get the message the user sent our Twilio number
    body = request.values.get('Body', None)

    # start our TwiML response
    resp1 = MessagingResponse()

    resp1.message('Hi! Please enter your name')

    return(str(resp1))
```

...but then how do I make it execute the 2nd part of the workflow?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here!

We recommend building conversations like this using sessions - you can check out a tutorial for that using Python and Flask here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-create-sms-conversations-python

So you could do something like:

```
from flask import Flask, request, session
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse

# The session object makes use of a secret key.
SECRET_KEY = 'a secret key'
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

@app.route("/sms", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def sms_logic():
    # Increment the counter
    counter = session.get('counter', 0)
    counter += 1

    # Save the new counter value in the session
    session['counter'] = counter

    resp = MessagingResponse()

    if counter == 1:
        resp.message('Hi! Please enter your name')
    else:
        body = request.values.get('Body', 'Friend')
        resp.message('Thanks {}!'.format(body))    

    return str(resp)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

For a bigger example check out this tutorial on building an Employee directory with Python and Flask: https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/employee-directory-python-flask

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!